# Confusion Matrix using logistic-regression python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I need help creating a confusion matrix from my model. Ive seen multiple sources use yhat or y_prediction, I thought weight was that. But nothing i do is working and Ive tried several things. My model doesnt use scikit-learn but im open to using it for the confusion matirx.

````
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 55)
x_train

x_train = x_train.T
x_test = x_test.T
y_train = y_train.T
y_test = y_test.T

def sigmoid(x):
  return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
def model(X, Y, learningRate, iterations):
  m= x_train.shape[1]
  n = x_train.shape[0]
  weight = np.zeros((n,1)) # initialize weights with zeros 
  bias = 0.0 

  costlist = []

  for i in range(iterations):

    z = np.dot(weight.T, X) + bias    #dot is vector multiplication & .T tranpose data 
    activation = sigmoid(z) 

    #cost function (propagate)
    cost = -(1/m)*np.sum(Y*np.log(activation) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-activation))
   

    #gradient (backward propagate)
    dw = (1/m)*np.dot(activation-Y, X.T) 
    db = (1/m)*np.sum(activation - Y)
    
    
    weigt = weight - learningRate*dw.T
    bias = bias - learningRate*db

    costlist.append(cost)

    if (i%(iterations/10)==0):
    #if i % 100 == 0:

      print("cost after", i, "iterations is:", cost)
      

  return weight, bias, costlist 
def accuracy(X, Y, weight, bias):
    
    z = np.dot(weight.T, X) + bias
    activation = sigmoid(z)
    
    activation = activation > 0.5
    
    activation = np.array(activation, dtype = 'int64')
    
    accuracy = (1 - np.sum(np.absolute(activation - Y))/Y.shape[1])*100
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I've got this one from my classes anotations (credits to my Professor Carla), it uses scikit, hopefuly it will come in handy for you!

```
import sklearn.metrics as skm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def mat_conf(Xmeasured, ymeasured, model,data_name): #data name is a string which you would like to entitle your confusion matrix
    Y_pred_prob = model.predict(Xmeasured)
    Y_pred = np.round(Y_pred_prob) # 50% limiar
    cmat=skm.confusion_matrix(ymeasured,Y_pred)
    cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cmat) 

    ax= plt.subplot()
    sns.heatmap(cm_df,annot=True, cmap = sns.color_palette("light:firebrick", as_cmap=True),fmt="d",cbar=False)
    plt.title('Test')


    ax.set_xlabel('Predicted');ax.set_ylabel('Real'); 
    ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix: '+data_name); 
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['label 1', 'label 2']); ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['with something', 'without that']);
    return

#mat_conf(x_train, y_train, model,'Train Data')
```